# How do I convert a setup.py file to an egg file for Deulge 3rd party plugins in Windows?

Tags: python, cmd.exe, deluge

I do not understand how to change a 3rd party plugin into an egg file using python. An egg file is the only file the deluge will accept as a proper plugin. The problem is that all the third party plugins come in as zip files with a setup.py file in them which does not work as a plugin.

Comment: If you are going to ask and answer your own question you need to make your question look like a real question.

Comment: Fixed it, now it should be much clearer and not confuse everyone. Thanks so much for the advice.

Comment: It's still not a question. A question would look something like "How do I install a 3rd Party Deluge Plugin in Windows?". The content of the question should expand on what is in the title. You can read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Imagine you didn't know what the answer was. How would you write it so somebody else could answer it? You need some kind of problem statement, like for example "I want to do xyx. I tried abc but it didn't work. How can I achieve xyz?

Comment: You can leave out "If you have a better answer I am all ears.". If someone has a better answer they will post it anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You need to already have python installed so that it can be called from the command prompt.
2. Download your 3rd party plugin as a zip. ex. [AutoRemovePlus](https://github.com/omaralvarez/deluge-autoremoveplus)
3. Extract that plugin to a folder.
4. Shift right click in the folder and click "Open command window here"
5. Now run "python setup.py bdist_egg" - this will created a folder within that folder called dist.
6. Open dist, in there you will now have a file called "AutoRemovePlus-0.5-py2.7.egg" it might be 2.6 , make sure you rename it to whatever version of python your deluge uses. [Version Check](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Troubleshooting#PythonVersion)
7. Now follow the instructions to install that egg file as you would any other deluge plugin. [Deluge Plugin Install] "dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Plugins#InstallingPluginEggs"
8. You should now be able to use the plugin.